# Upload TFS process Template | via C# or command prompt

Tags: c#, visual-studio, command-line, command-prompt, tfs-2015

Is there a way to upload a TFS process template to a tfs server in one go, or do i have to upload every single file one after another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working with command line([witadmin importwitd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd312129.aspx)) you may have to upload every single file one after another.

If you want to upload one at a time into one team project. You can through Power shell script to achieve this. Example as below:

```
Param(
      [string] $CollectionUrlParam = $(Read-Host -prompt "Collection (enter to pick):"), 
      [string] $TeamProjectName = $(Read-Host -prompt "Team Project:"),
      [string] $ProcessTemplateRoot = $(Read-Host -prompt "Process Template Folder:")
      )

$TeamProjectName = "teamswithareas"
$ProcessTemplateRoot = "C:\Users\mrhinsh\Desktop\TfsProcessTemplates\Microsoft Visual Studio Scrum 3.0 - Preview"
$CollectionUrl = "http://kraken:8080/tfs/tfs01"

$TFSConfig = "${env:ProgramFiles}\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 11.0\Tools\TFSConfig.exe"
$WitAdmin = "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\witadmin.exe"

witds = Get-ChildItem "$ProcessTemplateRoot\WorkItem TrackingType\Definitions"

foreach ($witd in $witds)
{
   Write-Host "Importing $witd"
   & $WitAdmin importwitd /collection:$CollectionUrl /p:$TeamProjectName /f:$($witd.FullName)
}
$WitAdmin importcategories /collection:$CollectionUrl /p:$TeamProjectName /f:"$ProcessTemplateRoot\WorkItem Tracking\Categories.xml"
$WitAdmin importprocessconfig /collection:$CollectionUrl /p:$TeamProjectName /f:"$ProcessTemplateRoot\WorkItem Tracking\Process\ProcessConfiguration.xml"
```

More detailed info please refer [this blog](https://binary-stuff.com/post/upgradepublish-tfs-2013-process-templates-with-powershell).